# How do I create gnome-terminal profiles at a global level (for all users)?

Tags: gnome, dconf

I need to add several custom gnome-terminal profiles for all users on a system (ldap authenticated, so the config needs to be pulled in at login).

I can currently create the profiles using an autostart script to run dconf load inside the user session, but this seems like a clunky approach.

I read the [dconf System Administrator Guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators), followed their instructions to create a profile, pointing at /etc/dconf/db/site.d/, and added a file 00_gnome-terminal-profiles similar to the file I was passing to dconf load above with a bunch of paths and keys that I want to set:

```
[/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:]
list=['b3d99b34-7f2c-416b-b662-f6275b470f0b', '8a4099b8-76c9-4543-9992-70824eb39316']
default='8a4099b8-76c9-4543-9992-70824eb39316'

[/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:8a4099b8-76c9-4543-9992-70824eb39316]
visible-name='Standard'
use-theme-transparency=false

[/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b3d99b34-7f2c-416b-b662-f6275b470f0b]
foreground-color='rgb(255,255,255)'
visible-name='MFG'
use-custom-command=true
custom-command='/usr/bin/sshaskuser host1'
use-transparent-background=false
use-theme-colors=false
use-theme-transparency=false
background-color='rgb(37,41,45)'
scrollback-lines=24
scrollbar-policy='never'
```

But when I run dconf update, I get the following error:

```
# dconf update
/etc/dconf/db/dbw.d/00_gnome-terminal-profiles: ignoring invalid group name: /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:
/etc/dconf/db/dbw.d/00_gnome-terminal-profiles: ignoring invalid group name: /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:8a4099b8-76c9-4543-9992-70824eb39316
/etc/dconf/db/dbw.d/00_gnome-terminal-profiles: ignoring invalid group name: /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b3d99b34-7f2c-416b-b662-f6275b470f0b
```

Of course, I know the paths don't exist, I need to create them - how do I do that (or how do I solve my problem in the correct manner)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is an old post but I had this same problem and thought it might be worth answering for someone else who might make the same mistake.  Looking at the code for dconf update it appears that the '/' prefix is invalid.  Looking at the example from the dconf administrator's guide (included in the OP) indeed shows that they DO NOT include the leading '/' in the group name.

Comment: Nice first post! Thanks for taking the time - gave it a quick check and you nailed it.